# sin inverse in Iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I wanted to calculate sin inverse ..so i did this:

```
   float radians =  asinf(1.1205);
NSLog(@"%f",radians);
```

Output is something like "nano"....any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot take the arcsine of a number outside [-1, 1]. There is no angle that can produce a sine outside of that range.

Answer (score 0):

The output is `nan`, which means "Not a number".

The output range of sine is [-1, 1], so the inverse sine of any number larger than 1 is meaningless on the real line. Do you want a complex number or what?